# Selecting specific rows from DELETED table within a trigger

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers

I have an intermediate table that defines many-to-many relationship between, for instance, `Customer` and `Orders`, like this:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE Example
GO 

USE [Example]
GO 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerOrders](
   [CustomerId] [int],
   [OrderId]  [int]
)
GO

INSERT INTO CustomerOrders (CustomerId, OrderId) VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO CustomerOrders (CustomerId, OrderId) VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO CustomerOrders (CustomerId, OrderId) VALUES (2, 1)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CustomerOrdersRemoved]
   ON  [dbo].[CustomerOrders]
   FOR DELETE
AS 
   BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   --IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT CustomerId FROM CustomerOrders 
                    INNER JOIN deleted ON CustomerOrders.CustomerId=deleted.CustomerId)
   --this wont work
END
GO

DELETE CustomerOrders WHERE OrderId=1
GO
```

Now, I need to have an `ON DELETE` trigger on this table, which would need to update another table based on customers who *don't* have any orders left in the table. In this case, after the `DELETE` operation the customer with `CustomerId=1` will have 1 order with `OrderId=2` left and customer with `CustomerId=2` will have no orders left. So I need to get only customer with `CustomerId=2` from the *deleted* `vtable` within the trigger.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hands are faster than my head :-/

The answer is

`SELECT CustomerId FROM deleted WHERE CustomerId NOT IN (SELECT CustomerId FROM CustomerOrders)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using deleted.CustomerId on the right side of a comparison.

I was doing something similar to what you're doing.

and the solution is to define a @variable to hold deleted.CustomerId (After your SET NO COUNT line), then compare CustomerOrders.CustomerId to the variable.

EDIT:
Here's the code which works just fine, It is a trigger to update movie rating by the average rating it got from tblRating(MovieID, UserID, rating) which also represents a many-to-many relationship between tblMovies and tblUsers, this one uses inserted but it is the same with deleted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trUpdateRating
ON [dbo].[tblRating]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @rate float, @mid int
SET @rate = 0;

-- here is the assignment I was talking about and it is valid
SELECT @mid=MovieID from inserted;

SELECT @rate=AVG(isnull(Rating, 0)) FROM tblRating WHERE MovieID=@mid;

-- and here is the comparison
UPDATE tblMovies
SET avg_rating = @rate
WHERE ID=@mid;
END
```

Comment: you cant do something like this: @variable=(SELECT CustomerId FROM deleted), because it will throw when a trigger will be fired on deletion of multiple rows and as they cannot be assigned to 1 variable.

Comment: I see, the situation is different.